# HTML 5 datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I use HTML5 and jquery datepicker.

script:

```
$( "#myDate" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
});
```

html:

```
<input type="date" name="myDate" id="myDate" value="">
```

When I try the example on the browser it shows me the jquery datepicker. When instead I try the example on a android device it shows me the native android datepicker and after selection of a date it shows me the jquery datepicker.

How would it be possible to show just the android datepicker when I am on an android device? Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do it would to have two date pickers, one for mobile and one for desktop. Then use a media query to display the mobile and hide the desktop when viewing on smaller screens.

Like this

HTML

```
<input type="date" name="myDate" id="myDate" value="">
<input type="date" name="myDate" id="mobile" value="">
```

css

```
#mobile{display: none}

@media (max-width: 600px){
#mobile{display: inline}
#myDate{display: none}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method:

```js
var isAndroid = /android/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

if (isAndroid)
{
  alert("mobile device");
}
else
{
  alert("not a mobile device");
}
```